# Cannot get any data from Google Fit History API

Tags: android, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am trying to use the google fit history api to get the steps I took within the last week separated by day. My app does not record any data, I just want to use the history api to get the data on the fit store. According to my account on https://fit.google.com/ I took 151 steps 3 days ago, but when I try to get the number of steps taken each day I get back a result with 0 data sets. When I use the following code I get back 7 buckets but each of these buckets contains 0 data sets. I think I must be approaching this wrong somehow, but I am not sure where.

```
 private class GetData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date now = new Date();
        cal.setTime(now);
        long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
        cal.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, -1);
        long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();


        DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
                .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA, DataType.AGGREGATE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .build();

            System.out.println("here");
        DataReadResult dataReadResult =
                Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        System.out.println(dataReadResult.getBuckets().size());
        System.out.println(dataReadResult.getDataSets().size());
```

Answer (score 0):

There're some probable causes:

1) Have you subscribed this type of data yet?

2) Your app doesn't connect properly with google service. Have you created OAuth Client ID from Google develop console? This's compulsory in instruction of google to connect to its GG Fit service (Please notice that, if you clone another app, on the same computer or not, you need to re-create another OAuth Client ID and one more thing you need 2 separating accounts, one to login Google develop console to create OAuth Client ID and one to sign in after starting your app, and it will ask you to sign in to accept its permission,... not sure why it's is, but it would work)

Note: Btw you can make a search about Google setting in your device (Setting --> Google), Here you can find which app connects to google service (including GG Fit service). I recommend you disconnect all and delete OAuth Client ID, your app, then re-create all of them!

Mttdat.